# How do i make so the div's overlap with eachother?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do i make that when i press a button instead of that the div like dropping under the div the the maybe 'home' div disappear when i fire the other show hidden div ?

Here's the Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#hideshow2').live('click', function (event) {
        jQuery('#content2').toggle('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: `live` is deprecated, use `on`

Comment: use position=absolute or fixed

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly what you are trying to do? If you could include some HTML that would be useful too.

Comment: " How do i make that when i press a button instead of that the div like dropping ".... what ?

Comment: im trying to open one div and when i press the home the div that is open closes and a new div appears
http://jsfiddle.net/6xWvb/1/

Comment: Lol but i change the live to the on tag but it won't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pretty easy.....   See this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/RCfVX/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#homebtn').click(function (event) {
        jQuery('#one').toggle();
        jQuery('#two').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Horrid colours in your fiddle. Upvoted for right answer but still horrid colours lol.